# Can't get Kestrel to start using .NET 5.0 and Linux Docker

Tags: .net, linux, docker, asp.net-web-api, dockerfile

First of all. Sorry for not understanding this 100% but I'm very new to this.
I am trying to have a .NET 5.0 WebApi running on Linux Docker and using HTTPS.
I have issued a cert on my windows machine and copied it to .aspnet/https in my home folder on the Linux machine. I have copied the UserSecrets from my windows machine to .microsoft/usersecrets on the Linux machine.

The Linux machine is a rapsberry pi 3 running a Debian 10 OS.

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5000:80 -p 5001:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Development__Password=[Password] -v ${HOME}/.microsoft/usersecrets/:/home/[userName]/.microsoft/usersecrets -v ${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/home/[userName]/.aspnet/https/ dockerbuild
```

If in run above it get an exception

```
Unable to start Kestrel.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
```

If I try to use the dotnet dev-certs https on the server its telling me

```
A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.
```

Please let me know if I missed some information that is needed.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md?

Comment: Assuming `[username]` is a placeholder? Couple of things - 1. Does the `.pfx` filename match the Assembly name?  2. You may also need to specify `-e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path="/home/[userName]/.aspnet/https/<your-certificate-name>.pfx"`